# How to make a C++ program that works with a .txt file without showing it

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, fstream, configuration-files

My program needs to use a hidden text file to keep track of user's name.

But when the program starts, if it can't find the 'Name.txt' file in the same directory, it generates one that is visible to the user.

The user can view it, edit it, and so on. How can I prevent this from happening, so that only my program can modify the file?

Also, is there a better way to keep knowledge of the name of the user (keep in mind I'm new to programming in general, not only to C++)?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream example;
    example.open("Name.txt");
    getline(example, line);
    if (line.compare("") == 0)
    {
        example.close();
        string con;
        cout << "Welcome to this program!\n";
        cout << "Do you want to register? (y/n) ";
        cin >> con;
        con[0] = tolower(con[0]);
        if (con.compare("n") != 0)
        {
            string name;
            ofstream one;
            one.open("Name.txt");
            cout << "What's your name? ";
            cin >> name;
            one << name;
            one.close();
            cout << "See you later " << name << ".";
            Sleep(4000);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Welcome back " << line << ".";
        example.close();
        Sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

EDIT : I just realised I said 'to keep track of the user'. Now I realized why you guys thought I wanted to do something bad with this program. I corrected it now, what I meant was 'to keep track of the user’s **name**'.

Comment: *"so that means that the user can view it, modify it etc..."* Why is that a problem?

Comment: Is it your computer or user's?

Comment: No I'm not trying to do something underhand with it, it's simply that it looks kind of stupid to me. Serious software doesn't show that crap, it's simply not user friendly, and I wish to keep the program compact, in one exe

Comment: Also if what I'm saying is stupid tell me, I'm not an expert in programming so any help is appreciated

Comment: @n.m. This is just testing things and having fun on my pc, but I don't get what is wrong with doing it on someone else's pc. I mean they told the program the name what's wrong with the program remembering it

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni:  The *standard* C++ language has no facilities for modifying the attributes of a file, such as hidden.  You'll need to use Operating System functions for that.  There is nothing forbidding you to modify the attributes after you access a file (unless the OS doesn't have the functionality).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what I meant for hidden was being a part of the exe in itself

Comment: @ThomasMatthews maybe something like system("attrib -h Name.txt") ?

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni I slightly updated your question, in order to highlight the question.   Note that you should not embed the data of the file into your code (even if it could be done):  if the software would be installed according to best practices, it would only be modifiable with administrative privilege.  In addition, code should be thought as something that is digitally signed.  If you'd need to update data in it, you'd need to resign the code everytime.  Your program would hence become a security risk.  Always keep mutable data separate from code.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni:  The `attrib` command will not work on Linux and some other operating systems.  If you are using Windows operating system, search the internet for "MSDN C++ set file attributes".  I'm not talking about the `system` command.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  Even though at times I use my usb drive to boot linux, I'm not compiling into .elf yet, simply because I'm trying to understand programming first and then try other things, but even if I wanted to build a version for linux, can't I just make a copy of the source code and modify that part of code with linux's equivalent? I'm not sure what it is but I think there is

Comment: Perhaps you should understand that hiding things on user's computer doesn't really work. Always assume that the user is able to read and modify everything you put on his computer.

Comment: My idea wasn't to make it deletable, I just wanted to make the user delete both the program and the file or not delete any of the two

Comment: I meant to say undeletable at the end of my last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to maintain a file that contains the names of all the registered users, or some other kind of current-user-independent data.

**The problem**

Your code tries to open the file in the current working directory of the program. Unfortunately, it depends on the way the user has launched your program.

It also ignores possible errors during the opening when reading the file.  So if the file isn't there, your code will open the file as `ofstream` for writing (which will create the file if it doesn't exist).

**How to solve it ?**

To fulfill your requirements, you should open the file in a predetermined location (for example fixed during the installation process, or in the program's configuration). See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/), on where to ideally store data and configuration files on windows platform.

If you want to make sure that the program only opens the file if it already exists, you should verify the result of the `open` on the `ifstream` and issue an error message if this failed:

```
example.open("Name.txt");
if (!example) {
    cout << "OUCH ! Fatal error: the registration file couldn't be opened !" <<endl; 
    exit (1);     
}
```

**How to protect the file against users ?**

Note however that if your program reads and writes data from the file, the user could find it also and edit it manually. This will be difficult to prevent.

Alternatively you could consider using the windows [registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724182(v=vs.85).aspx), which is less trivial for the user to edit (although not impossible).  The major inconvenience of this approach is that it's system dependent and it will make the porting of your code to other platforms much more difficult.

If you want to fully protect your file, you could as suggested by Chris in the comment, encrypt the file. Encryption is complex business; Consider using a library such as [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/crypto.html) or a [proven algorithm](https://www.schneier.com/academic/twofish/).

This will protect you against ordinary users.  But you'd still be exposed to hackers able to reverse engineer your code and to find the encryption key that must be somehow embedded in your code to decrypt the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do 'serious programs' cope with this? Also, I'm fine for the program to create the file if it doesn't exist, but as I said I don't want the user to be able to view the file, open it, delete it, modify it and blah blah blah so if this is not a convenient way, what is one?

Comment: Why not encrypt the content and add a checksum. It is not hidden but not readable and the checksum would prove it is not modified.

Comment: @chris thanks, I'll check how to do it since I have no clue about encryption .

Comment: Yes.  I've updated to provide additional information in this reagard

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Also, even if it's not secure, to make the program look more clean I added a

Comment: system("attrib +h Name.txt")   to make the file hidden (but you only need to change explorer's settings to see hidden files)

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni I think this is a very reasonable alternative if you're new to programming !

Comment: @Christophe What? Giving the file a hidden attribute using cmd built in functions?

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni yes, or working with [`SetFileAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) directly in your code without using `system()`.  As you are still new to programming, go for such simpler solutions, before investigating options that require much more programming skills (such as using a third party library and encryption).

Comment: *Thanks for the help, but how do 'serious programs' cope with this?* - they don't.  In any well-designed program, the user can delete or modify any and all configuration files if they want to.  (The program might stop working, but that's the users problem, not yours.)  Just make sure the files are in the right place, e.g., the user's application data folder, and not somewhere they'll be tempted to mess with like on the desktop or the My Documents folder.  Based on what you've told us so far, there's no need for the data to be encrypted.

Comment: @HarryJohnston   That was a good response to my question, thanks. But I'm sure that serious programs at least encrypt those files, if not you could simply read the files and try to figure out at least a part of how programs work right? If it's a open source program, even better. But if not... that's not something a company would like.

Comment: Managing settings is trivial, so it doesn't give any useful information to someone attempting to reverse engineer or duplicate the software.

Comment: @HarryJohnston oh ok. Thanks for the info